# How do I make a repeating background of a triangle image in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have a triangular icon I need to be used as a background image.  The triangles line up together right-side up, upside-down, etc. in rows.

The background may need to be adjusted dynamically, so I'd like to know how to grow it in any direction without tedious copy+paste (which might also lead to imperfections), Is this possible?

Comment: Alright, found what I was looking for.  'Create tiled clones'.  Could have used that 1.5 hours ago, though. :/

Comment: I have added it as a Community Wiki answer so that the question isn't sitting without an answer. @Hamster, if by some miracle you read this and you wish to answer this yourself, please do so and I will remove the CW one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The OP's answer, posted originally as a comment:

---

> Alright, found what I was looking for. 'Create tiled clones'. Could have used that 1.5 hours ago, though.